# Why do ESPN and others still list the Eagles as having a chance to win the NFC East title?

Tags: american-football, nfl

As of Christmas Day 2021 with 2 games to go for each the Cowboys at 10-4 and the Eagles at 7-7 why do ESPN and others still show the Eagles with a chance to win the NFC east division title?

Answer (score 4):

There are 17 games per season starting this season (2021-22).

Each team has 3 games left. If the Cowboys lose all remaining games and the Eagles win all remaining games, both teams will end up with a 10-7 record. They'll also both have identical division and conference records as well as having the head-to-head series tied at 1-1.

The Eagles would be able to win the division due to [strength of victory](https://www.dallascowboys.com/news/how-the-cowboys-can-clinch-the-nfc-east), which is the fifth tiebreaker.

Answer (score -2):

[Because the NFL moved to a 17 game season in 2021](https://www.cbssports.com/nfl/news/what-to-know-ahead-of-the-nfls-first-17-game-season-in-2021-here-are-the-changes-that-are-coming/). I'm not going to run through all the possibilities here to show there is a combination of results under which the Eagles win the division, but just going to trust ESPN and friends.